# Upload rotated image preview with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new in ReactJS and I am trying to upload rotated a preview of an image with ReactJS. I followed this stackoverflow question:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530791/rotating-image-preview-with-reactjs`

I was able to integrate but I am really stuck how I could possibly update the image state and upload.

I couldn't find any info about this situation and I also tried to integrate the way of uploading the cropped image but I just couldn't handle it.

This is how I get the image via Dropzone:

```
<Label as="label" htmlFor="upload">
  <div  className={styles.card}>
     <Dropzone
         onDrop={this.onImageDrop}
         accept="image/*"
         multiple={false}
      >
      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => {
          return (
            <div {...getRootProps()}>
               <input {...getInputProps()} />
               {
                 <p>
                 Upload your profile picture.
                 </p>
                }
              </div>
           );
        }}
        </Dropzone>

     </div>
     </Label>
     {this.state.uploadedFile === null ? '' : (
        <div>
          <RotateImage src={this.state.uploadedFile} />
        </div>
     )}
```

This is how I update profile_image:

```
 onImageDrop(files) {
    this.setState({
      profile_image: files[0],
      uploadedFile: URL.createObjectURL(files[0]),
    });
  }
```

This is the submit part of it(I pass it to redux):

```
onSubmit(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  const {
    profile_image
  } = this.state;

  fileUrl.append('profile_image', profile_image);

  this.props.createProfile(fileUrl, this.props.history);
}
```

This is my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { auth } = this.props;
    const { location } = auth;
    this.state = {
      uploadedFile: null
    };

    this.onImageDrop = this.onImageDrop.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

And this is my RotateImage component that I got from other stackoverflow question (all credits to them):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class rotateImage extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rotation: 0
    }

    this.rotate = this.rotate.bind(this);
    this.rotateleft = this.rotateleft.bind(this);
  }

  rotate(){
    let newRotation = this.state.rotation + 90;
    if(newRotation >= 360){
      newRotation =- 360;
    }
    this.setState({
      rotation: newRotation,
    })
  }

  rotateleft(){
    let newRotation = this.state.rotation - 90;
    if(newRotation >= 360){
      newRotation =- 360;
    }
    this.setState({
      rotation: newRotation,
    })
  }

  render(){
    const { rotation } =  this.state;
    return <div><img style={{transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`}} src={this.props.src} width="200" />
      <input onClick={this.rotateleft} type="button" value="left" />
      <input onClick={this.rotate} type="button" value="right" />
    </div>
  }
}

export default rotateImage;
```

I am trying to upload rotated image and I really don't know how I could update image state that is rotated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really following your question. Do you mean that you need to pass the state of the `rotateImage` component to the parent component?

Comment: So I am able to rotate image via <RotateImage /> and I have a form for profile_image and other form fields I am able to save the image with the code above, but saved image is not rotated. I gotta do something once I rotate the image to update profile_image. I don't know if I was clear. @Mitch